# Mongoose populate error Schema hasn't been registered for model. Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Hi they are my Mongoose Models:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('../../config/db-connect');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var modelSchema = new Schema({
 _id: Number,
 make: String,
 name: String
});

var Model = db.model('Model', modelSchema);

module.exports = Model;
```

And this is the other one:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('../../config/db-connect');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var preferenceSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  list: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Model' }],
});

var Preference = db.model('Preference', preferenceSchema);

module.exports = Preference;
```

If i try this query it send me an error.

```
Preference
.findOne()
.where('_id').equals(userId)
.populate('list', '_id make name')
.exec( function(err, result) {

if (err) {
    request.log(['server', 'database', 'error'], 'An error occured during the             execution of the query');
       }
```

> MissingSchemaError: Uncaught error: Schema hasn't been registered for model   "Model".
>     Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Comment: Is the file with the Model definition required anywhere in your project?

Comment: @ZeMoon only in the file with the query

Comment: What is db? You are calling db.model instead of mongoose.model

Comment: @ZeMoon thank you now it doesn't give me the error, but now i expect a return of this type : {"_id":"10206401549871679","list":[{"_id":610471012,"make":"xxxxx","name":"yyyy"},{"_id":610471013,"make":"zzzzz","name":"qqqqq"}]}

but it return me {"_id":"10206401549871679","list":[]}

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you tried the query where the array contains more than one object?

Comment: @ZeMoon yes in this moment i am trying with 3 object like these:
{"_id":"10206401549871679","list":[1964251,3795920,5648315]}

Comment: Remove the field selection part in the populate method.

Comment: @ZeMoon i have tryed but nothing... if i query without .populate it return me {"_id":"10206401549871679","list":[1964251,3795920,5648315]} , but if i set .populate('list') it return me  {"_id":"10206401549871679","list":[]}